# How to build the WP_Query using the code?

Tags: wp-query

E.g. I have something like that:

```
$continent = $_POST['continent'];

if ($continent != 0) {
    // get specific taxonomy e.g. with id=3 which is africa
    $continent_query =  array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'continent',
                    'field' => 'term_id',
                    'terms' => $continent 
                );
} else {
    // how to build query array to search all terms?
    // I DON"T KNOW THIS CODE!!!
    $continent_query =  array( ?????????????? );
}
```

I am sending continent variable via post form and it's an integer. If it's "0" (all contintent in select box) then I need to build the **$continent_query** to query all terms. If it's specific then query e.g. only 2 or 3 etc.

This is the query:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => array( 'post' ),
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'tax_query' =>  array(
                            $continent_query,
                        )
        );
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Any idea how to do that for "0"?

Comment: Just a question: Is `$content` actually `0` as in integer zero? Or is it `false`? Just curious what `type` it is (bool/int).

Comment: It's integer from a selectbox like: `<option value="0">All Continents</option>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$continent_query =  array(
   'taxonomy' => 'continent',
   'field' => 'term_id',
   'terms' => 0 != $continent ? $continent : get_terms('continent', array('fields'=>'ids'))
);
```

Comment: great edit, @kaiser